# How to count number of elements in the following JSON

Tags: postgresql, metabase

I have a column in my Metabase table where the column entry is like the following:

```
{ “text_fields”: { “Weight”: “{:optional=>true, :priority=>4, :index=>false}” }, “checkbox_fields”: {}, “dropdown_fields”: { “Brand Name”: “{:optional=>false, :priority=>1, :index=>false, :options=>[“Non Branded”]}” }}
```

I want to get a net count of
text_fields
checkbox_fields
dropdown_fields

The desired answer, in this case, will be: 2 (1 text field + 0 checkbox field + 1 dropdown field)

Comment: Use [json_each function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) then just `count()` result grouped/filtered by `key`

Comment: Hi @Abelisto ,

Thank you for your answer. Maybe I am using this function wrong but I also want all the other columns present as well.

The function json each works in the from clause like this:

Select * from json each(json)

But my field is a column in a big table and I want all the other data as well.

Is there any other solution?

This gives me a syntax error.

Comment: @IshanPurohit Your question is missing `create table` details so we don't know table structure

Comment: @IshanPurohit your JSON is not valid - could you please use "Edit post" and fix the example data you entered?

Comment: @IshanPurohit `(values(1::int, '{"a": {"x":1}, "b": {}}'::json)) select *, (select count(*) from json_each(j) where key in ('a', 'b') and not value::jsonb = '{}'::jsonb) from t;` Note conversion values to `jsonb` type because there are no comparison operators for `json` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jsonb_each` to iterate over object keys/values, and `jsonb_object_keys` to extract the keys only.

Example (with sample data included):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ;
                                          mycolumn                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"text_fields": {"Weight": 1}, "checkbox_fields": {}, "dropdown_fields": {"Brand Name": 1}}
(1 row)


SELECT *,
  (SELECT sum((SELECT count(*) FROM jsonb_object_keys(v1)))
   FROM jsonb_each(mycolumn) AS j1(k1,v1)
   WHERE k1 IN ('text_fields', 'checkbox_fields', 'dropdown_fields')
  ) AS mytotal
FROM mytable;

                                          mycolumn                                           | mytotal 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------
 {"text_fields": {"Weight": 1}, "checkbox_fields": {}, "dropdown_fields": {"Brand Name": 1}} |       2
(1 row)
```